# Apache Cordova : impossible to see pictures on iOS 9.0

Tags: ios, cordova

I am making a mobile application with Apache Cordova.
My `index.html` file is simple:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="app">
            <h1>Apache Cordova</h1>
            <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
                <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
                <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
            </div>
            <img style="width:100%;" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFl3d.jpg" />
            <img style="width:100%;" src="original.jpg" />
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

It's not complicated:

I want to see 2 pictures:

■ **Online picture**

http://www.diana.dti.ne.jp/~june1/perfume/perfume_voce.jpg

■ **Picture in same folder than index.html**

original.jpg

I don't know why, it works on iOS 8.4 but doesn't work on iOS 9.0

▽ Sorry Stackoverflow blocks my screenshot (because I am a new member), so you can see this pictures on this page: https://openclassrooms.com/forum/sujet/apache-cordova-impossible-de-voir-image-externes

This is your picture:

■ **on iOS 8.4**

[image]

■ **on iOS 9.0**

[image]

Where is my error and why it's doesn't it work on iOS 9.0 now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably your http request is blocked by default in ios.

You have to set the NSAllowsArbitraryLoads key to YES under NSAppTransportSecurity dictionary in your .plist file.

refer to this link: [Transport security has blocked a cleartext HTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31254725/transport-security-has-blocked-a-cleartext-http/32560433#32560433)